# Dangerous pointer cast results in loss of const qualification

Tags: c, pointers, casting, constants

According to the ISO C Standard (6.3.16.1), a pointer can only be assigned to another pointer if "both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all of the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right". 
I got that warning in my static analyses tool, But I am not sure if there is a real problem or not. Because as you can see at the code below, that pointer will be passed to function that has "const" qualifier in it's prototype

```
int main()
{
    static volatile const signed int batu[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    unsigned int x = 5;
    func(x, (signed int *) batu);
}

signed int func(unsigned int p1, volatile const signed int *p2)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no section `6.3.16`, less a `.1` in the standard. What ever you use as reference is not ISO9899.

Comment: Never use casts if 1) they are not absolutely required or 2) you don't understand **all** implications of the cast or 3) you don't accept them completely. So, **why** do you use that cast?

Comment: It's section `6.5.16.1/1` (C99)

Comment: @atturri: C99 is **not** C standard!

Comment: The dangers are not just because of removing `const` as that is a guarantee the programmer gives and just results in less optimised code, but possibly worse because of the `volatile` qualifier which changes semantics for the compiler.

Comment: @Olaf. I don't mind if it's the **current** standard or not. It is the standard where the quote in the question can be read. You will not find that quote in the latest C standard.

Comment: @atturri actually I copy pasted that from static analysis tool. Iam not sure if its correct

Comment: @atturri: There is only one C standard and that is not C99! This question explicitly asks about the C standard, so it **very well** minds if C99 is standard or not.

Comment: 1) Rather than describe the warning: "got that warning", posting the exact warning is more useful. 2) When citing the standard, best to either a) use the current standard (now C11) or include the version of the standard used like "ISO C Standard (C99 6.3.16.1)" 3) Is this as simple as `func()` is declared _after_ its use?

Comment: @chux it is exact copy paste of QAC static analysis output. But code is imitation of problematic code

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the `(signed int *)` cast you have in your call to the function. Variable `batu` and the argument `p2` expected at the function are of the same type (see below), qualifiers included, so you don't need a cast at all.

An array type is always automatically converted to its equivalent pointer type except when it's an input to the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators. From the C standard 6.3.2.1/3.

Comment: Atturi you are quite right but this code generated by matlab and changing it manually is not suggested. Actually I am trying to understand if that error is genuine or not

Comment: @batgun: That error is indeed critical. And IMHO a tool which generates unnecessary and (potentially) dangerous casts should be trashed asap. That is even more true for widely used tools.

Comment: @batgun In this particular case, if you have not left out any relevant code, it is false alarm. But if code uses pointer for which `volatile` has been removed for other purposes, it can be potentially harmful.

Comment: @olaf what do you think about prototype of func(). It has volatile const in it's definition. So it will re-gain const qualifier in that function? For example when I try to change value in that function scope,compiler is angry withme

Comment: @batgun Yes, if you pass pointer to unqualified type as function argument, and argument is pointer to qualified type, then those qualifications are "gained" for the duration of the function, as long as you access it through that argument variable.

Comment: There actually is a third exception in the standard.

Comment: @batgun: Did you read my other comment? `const` is the less of a problem than the `volatile` qualifier. I think I was quite clear about my position. Maybe you have to parametrise the tool or update. It is definitively a fault you should report if that is the current version.

Comment: @olaf you are right but as we discussed with user694733 cant we justify that warning with that clarification?

Comment: @batgun: Not sure what you mean with "justify that warning". The warning is very well justified. I'd not give any guarantee every compiler will handle that correctly; at least it depends on the overall context (I somehow doubt you showed all code). I'd either think about not using Mathlab for this code or check if there is a way to get it generate correct code. After all, there is no need for the cast at all. I'd be worries about which other "flaws" (or actual errors) it produces.

Comment: Actually its imitation of problematic code. As lt's seen lt ls not an error and can be justified with a pcomment in our project. This is very huge project,probably more than you expected so it would be very hard to solve all problems especially when it is Matlab output.